# Retrieve all functions and attributes from an already instanced parent in the child class

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I'm trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361992/initialise-child-class-with-instance-of-parent-class) : Initialise child class with instance of parent class.

genomic_feature_instance is instanced and contains what follows :

> {'name': 'ENSG00000223972.5', 'type': 'gene', 'iv': , 'source': 'HAVANA',
>   'score': '.', 'frame': '.', 'attr' : {'ID': 'ENSG00000223972.5',
>   'gene_id': 'ENSG00000223972.5', 'gene_type':
>   'transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene', 'gene_status': 'KNOWN',
>   'gene_name': 'DDX11L1', 'leve l': '2', 'havana_gene':
>   'OTTHUMG00000000961.2'}}

I want to create a custom/child instance to manipulate attributes and functions from this class of genomic_feature_instance.

```
 aCustomGenomicFeature = CustomGenomicFeature(genomic_feature_instance,'kikou')
```

This is what I have done but I would like to use super() to inherit all attribute values from this genomic_feature (instance of GenomicFeature)

```
class CustomGenomicFeature(GenomicFeature):

    def __init__(self,genomic_feature_instance,kikou):

        # call parent constructor to set name and color 
        self.genomic_feature = genomic_feature_instance
        # Subclass-specific stuff follows
        self.kikou=kikou
```

Answer (score 0):

### With __dict__.update

I would rather advice the use of `__dict__` instead of `super`, because super won't help you to copy the value of the attributes of the parent object. So you could do something like that:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.__dict__.update(a.__dict__)

a = A()
b = B(a)

print(b.x)  # displays '1'

a.x = 3
b2 = B(a)

print(b2.x)  # displays '3'. Without the __dict__update, it would return '1'
```

That way you set every attribute your parent class has without modifying the attributes of the child class that the parent does not have.

In your case:

```
class CustomGenomicFeature(GenomicFeature):

    def __init__(self,genomic_feature_instance,kikou):

        super().__init__()
        self.__dict__.update(genomic_feature_instance.__dict__)

        # Subclass-specific stuff follows
        self.kikou=kikou
```

### With Composition

Another way (and probably more clean), would be to use **composition** instead of inheritance:

```
class CustomGenomicFeature(GenomicFeature):

    def __init__(self,genomic_feature_instance,kikou):

        # keep ref to the genomic_feature_instance
        self._genomic_feature = genomic_feature_instance

        # Subclass-specific stuff follows
        self.kikou=kikou

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._genomic_feature.name
```

### More:

- [Inheritance vs. Composition](https://codefellows.github.io/sea-python-401d4/lectures/inheritance_v_composition.html)

Comment: Ok but then you need to define all properties from the parent class then...well ok but i you have many attributes that can be long and I also want to keep function from parent, so inheritance was not so bad idea , no?

Comment: I edited the dict update solution to add the super method, that should do the trick

Comment: super().__init__()
  File "python3/src/HTSeq/_HTSeq.pyx", line 1063, in HTSeq._HTSeq.AlignmentWithSequenceReversal.__init__
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (0 given) . ... The init method from parent need parameters to be set or I don't know how the init parent is initialized.